# Get Java reflection representation of Scala type

Tags: java, scala, reflection

This seems like a simple question, but it's very challenging to search for, so I'm asking a new question. My apologies if it's already been asked.

Due to the compiler bug described here [Scala 2.11.5 compiler crash with type aliases and manifests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510867/scala-2-11-5-compiler-crash-with-type-aliases-and-manifests) (also here https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9155), I need to use scala `TypeTag`s and friends for discovery of type parameters to methods. However, I then need to use that type information in a Java library that uses `java.lang.Class` and `java.lang.reflect.Type`.

How can I convert a `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` `Type` into a `java.lang.reflect.Type` or `java.lang.Class`?

Put concretely, how would I fill out the body of this method:

```
def typeFor[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): java.lang.reflect.Type = ...
```

or, if that's not possible:

```
def typeFor[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): java.lang.Class[T] = ...
```

And note, due to the bug posted above, I cannot use `scala.reflect.Manifest`.

Comment: If you're willing to require a `ClassTag` rather than a `TypeTag` you can then just call `.runtimeClass` on it.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901823/any-way-to-obtain-a-java-class-from-a-scala-2-10-type-tag-or-symbol

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, but you can try to do something similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787163/get-a-java-lang-reflect-method-from-a-reflect-runtime-universe-methodsymbol/16791962#16791962). However [there is an open ticket...](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7317).

Answer (score 1):

This may have some limitations I'm not aware of, but you could drop down to Java reflection and try something like:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

def typeMe[T](implicit t: TypeTag[T]) = {
  catching(classOf[Exception]) opt Class.forName(t.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass.fullName)
}

println(typeMe[String])
println(typeMe[ClassTag[_]])
```

Results in:

```
Some(class java.lang.String)
Some(interface scala.reflect.ClassTag)
```

Comment: After playing with it for a bit, I came up with this: def typeFor(tpe: ScalaType) = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).runtimeClass(tpe). Which seems to work, but I'm not sure if there's some hidden problems with it.

Comment: Cool. I thought you had needed a Java object, that method looks like it returns a RuntimeClass object. Glad you're making progress.

Comment: In the context of a runtimeMirror, it is a Class object. But you do have to perform an unsafe cast.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it with manifests, was:

```
  private def typeFromManifest(m: Manifest[_]): Type = {
if (m.typeArguments.isEmpty) { m.runtimeClass }
else new ParameterizedType {
  def getRawType = m.runtimeClass
  def getActualTypeArguments = m.typeArguments.map(typeFromManifest).toArray
  def getOwnerType = null
}
```

}

Right now I'm trying to solve this using something other than Manifest which should be removed from scala runtime.