# Get Scala annotation from Java Method

Tags: java, scala, methods, reflection, annotations

I have an instance of Java `Method` that represents a Scala function with a Scala annotation (that extends `StaticAnnotation`). I know I can use `Method.getAnnotation(classOf[SomeJavaAnnotation])` to get a Java annotation, but this returns `null` for Scala annotations.

How can I get the Scala annotation from this? It seems I need to convert it to a Scala `MethodSymbol` first, but I don't see an obvious way to do that and I've only seen resources showing how to go the other way (from Scala `MethodSymbol` to Java `Method`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala annotations are invisible for Java reflection.

Either

- use Java annotations (with runtime retention policy), then they will be visible for Java reflection, or
- use [Scala reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html), it can see Scala annotations.

---

This is how `java.lang.reflect.Method` can be converted into `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol`

```scala
import java.lang.reflect.Method
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def methodToMethodSymbol(method: Method): MethodSymbol = {
  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(method.getDeclaringClass)
  classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TermName(method.getName)).asMethod // (*)
}
```

If there are overloaded versions of the method, you'll have to replace
the line (*)
with

```scala
classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TermName(method.getName)).alternatives.find(
  _.asMethod.paramLists.flatten.map(_.typeSignature.erasure.typeSymbol.asClass) == 
    method.getParameterTypes.map(runtimeMirror.classSymbol).toList
).get.asMethod
```

Another implementation:

```scala
def methodToMethodSymbol(method: Method): MethodSymbol = {
  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val castedRuntimeMirror = runtimeMirror.asInstanceOf[{
    def methodToScala(meth: Method): scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#MethodSymbol
  }]

  castedRuntimeMirror.methodToScala(method).asInstanceOf[MethodSymbol]
}
```

Testing:

```scala
class myAnnotation extends StaticAnnotation

class MyClass {
  @myAnnotation
  def myMethod(i: Int): Unit = ()
}

val clazz = classOf[MyClass]
val method = clazz.getMethod("myMethod", classOf[Int])
  
val methodSymbol = methodToMethodSymbol(method) // method myMethod
methodSymbol.annotations // List(myAnnotation)
```

---

Just in case, here is reverse conversion of `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol` into `java.lang.reflect.Method`

```scala
def methodSymbolToMethod(methodSymbol: MethodSymbol): Method = {
  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val classSymbol = methodSymbol.owner.asClass
  val clazz = runtimeMirror.runtimeClass(classSymbol)
  val paramClasses = methodSymbol.paramLists.flatten.map(paramSymbol =>
    runtimeMirror.runtimeClass(paramSymbol.typeSignature.erasure)
  )
  clazz.getMethod(methodSymbol.name.toString, paramClasses: _*)
}
```

Another implementation:

```scala
def methodSymbolToMethod(methodSymbol: MethodSymbol): Method = {
  type InternalMethodSymbol = scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#MethodSymbol
  val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
  val castedRuntimeMirror = runtimeMirror.asInstanceOf[{
    def methodToJava(sym: InternalMethodSymbol): Method
  }]

  castedRuntimeMirror.methodToJava(
    methodSymbol.asInstanceOf[InternalMethodSymbol]
  )
}
```

[Get a java.lang.reflect.Method from a reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787163/get-a-java-lang-reflect-method-from-a-reflect-runtime-universe-methodsymbol)

Comment: Is it possible to perform Scala reflection on a Java `Method`? I only have access to the `Method` instance.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the annotation I wanted with `methodSymbol.annotations.find(_.tree.tpe == typeOf[MyAnnotation])`